# Spring application should start even database is not available at startup

Tags: spring, tomcat, jndi

I have an old spring application which uses jee:jndi-lookup for datasource. This application running on Tomcat 8.

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/Tomcat8Database" destroy-method="close" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" lookup-on-startup="false"/>
```

The database may be sometime down at startup of the application, but as I also tried to lazy-init spring beans it did not helped as what it seems like that JNDI lookup in spring happened on Startup always or its not in spring controls as Server provide Pooling over connections.

Any idea or code example will be helpful.

Comment: Do you _know_ when the database is down before you start the app? (e.g. you want to support multiple profiles, one where you have the database, one where you don't) or you don't know and you want the application to be fault-tolerant of an database you expect to be there, to not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to spring [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html#setLookupOnStartup-boolean-), For a lazy lookup, a proxy interface needs to be specified.

Proxy interface specify the proxy interface to use for the JNDI object.
Typically used in conjunction with "lookupOnStartup"=false and/or "cache"=false. Needs to be specified because the actual JNDI object type is not known in advance in case of a lazy lookup.

Try:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/Tomcat8Database" destroy-method="close" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```